# I want to scroll every thing except button in view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using scroll view which scrolling everything perfectly but i have button at the top of view for dissmissing view i want it to remain there and do not scroll in swift .

[image]

Comment: add button outside the scrollview (on top)

Comment: I have full view Scroll view see screenshot attached. Thanks

Comment: add button to `self.view`

Comment: it,s not working when i place it in top of view then it placed again in scroll view

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the button to the view?

Comment: i have used view controller not in code.Thanks

Comment: give view controller screenshot

Comment: i have attached it already with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add first `UIScrollView` and then `UIButton` to `self.view`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer it worked i tried it before myself but i was placing with mouse so it was again going to scroll view but moving it with keyboard arrows worked thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Add button outside scrollview content like overlay.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

```
class TmpVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var scoll : UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var btn : UIButton!
var btnPoint : CGPoint!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scoll.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 600)
    scoll.delegate = self
    btnPoint = btn.frame.origin

}    

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    btn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: btnPoint.x, y: btnPoint.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}


deinit {
    print("deinit Tmpvc")
}

}
```